# Ghostscript ps2pdf Create Cleaned pdf

Tags: linux, perl, ghostscript

I have tried and searched all but i didn't get answer for my requirement. Is it possible to create cleaned pdf file from ps2pdf command.

I know we can create pdf using this, My requirement is I have existing pdf and i am cropping into some area and i am creating ps file because i want to remove the other objects.

When i print the file, it will remove.

When i tried below command in my linux cent os

```
ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress a11.ps axd.pdf
```

Objects still remains.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If any portion of the object is not clipped out, then Ghostscript is forced to include the entire  object. It doesn't matter whether you output to PostScript or PDF, the same applies.

Comment: Thanks Ken<br/> Can we extract text and there coordinates using "pstotext" Can i get to know any ideas how to use pstotext, I have GS version "GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)"

Comment: OK firstly 8.70 is *ancient* (3.5 years old), I would very strongly reccomend you upgrade, the current version is 9.06 and 9.07 is due for release in a matter of weeks. If you use 9.06 you will have access to the new 'txtwrite' device which is specifically intended for text extraction. This device tries hard to get Unicode code points and deliver the co-ordinates and it sounds like what you need. Be aware that not everything in a PDF file that loos like text is actually text....